# How can I dynamically add custom client validation in Asp.Net Mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, razor, unobtrusive-validation

I want to be able to add the ModelClientValidationRule dynamically from inside the controller action.

Eg. based on certain condition I want to determine if client validation should be rendered. However I don't want to go all out and add this custom rule on all controllers by overriding the validation provider at the global level.

If this were a server side validation I'd do something like this, but instead I want to bind the client side validation before render - I do not know how.

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(){
    ModelState["SomePropertyKey"].Errors.Add( ... )
}
```

I'm looking for the secret sauce that will do this:

```
public ActionResult RenderSomething(){
    if(IsSomeCondition){
        <<Secret Sauce To Render the View with "X" ModelClientValidationRule>>
    }
}
```

I can go all out and circumvent the framework entirely but I prefer to work within it as much as possible.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Is it a requirement that this be inside the controller action? If not, one option would be to implement your own `ModelValidatorProvider`.

```
public class DynamicModelValidatorProvider : ModelValidatorProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<ModelValidator> GetValidators(
        ModelMetadata metadata,
        ControllerContext context)
    {
        // do your logic here, based off metadata or controllercontext.
        // you could return common DataAnnotation type validators
        return new RequiredAttributeAdapter(metadata, context, new RequiredAttribute());

        // or maybe your own custom validator?
    }
}
```

and in your global.asax

```
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new DynamicModelValidatorProvider());
```

If you're not interested in server-side stuff at all, implement your own custom `ModelValidator` that has a robust `GetClientValidationRules()` method but always returns success for `Validate()`

Comment: Yes I have to say this is the closest of all the answers. I considered this, but this is not flexible enough for what I need. The validation really has to be dynamic since it involves quite a bit of business logic. I can make it server side/remote validation, but the user wants responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question since your second code snippet is clearly server side code and you're talking about some client side way to achieve something. Why don't you add error to your ModelState depending on your condition ? Or maybe you could clarify your question to help me understand your need.

Comment: The 2nd code is serverside called during render, before post. I need the action to package client side validation based on certain condition. I don't see any straight forward way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking, for a given ViewModel I want all string properties with the word Phone in their name to have a particular validation, you could generate partial classes with the appropriate validation attributes and data annotations on them using T4 templates.

You can also write custom validations to extend jQuery-validate so your client could do this instead of the server.

if you are asking how do I apply a business rule globally you can look at making your own base controller that implements OnActionExecuting or one of the half dozen methods in the view rendering lifecycle. or implement an ActionFilterAttribute that does more or less the same thing but will give more flexibility.

If you are trying to do something like that is prevent a user from company A do actions on company B's data you can write an ActionFilterAttribute or you could do it at a lower level by writing a HttpModule that sit's in the pipeline and never let's this happen no matter what is going on in your web application.Also if you only use stored procedures to edit data you can implement this kind of thing on the database as well.

Given that you weren't clear about 'The special sauce' all I can say is that there are no particular rules for doing this. This important thing is to think about where applying the rule has the best effect.

Comment: Let me make it clear. I need this to happen at the controller action level. Or at the very least on ActionFilter. So depending on a few condition I want to inject custom client validation. Now I could go all out and build my own framework. Put the scripts into viewbag, bind them to the form etc. and execute them via jquery onload. But that's reinventing the wheel. Mvc has this mechanism somewhere I want to plug into that if possible.